# Spring Context init (java)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, dependency-injection

I'm a beginner with spring and I am having problem with basic context init and I can't find any easy tutorial.
So what I want to do is basic dependency injection and I have seen I only have to mark classes as @Componant or @Service and inject them directly within target fiels with @Autowired.
For this I need to set properly my spring context (I'll need to build a web service + use JPA so I want to build a webapp)

I'm using JDK 1.8, maven 3.2.1

I want to do a basic dependency injection.
=> I want to inject a storeImpl instance there but this lead to a null pointer exception
=> this work perfectly without injection ( private Store storeImpl = new storeImpl();  )

```
package com.mycompany.app.controller;

@Controller
public class Controller
{
    @Autowired
    private Store storeImpl;

    public void use()
    {
        storeImpl.get();
    }
}


package com.mycompany.app.store;

public interface Store {
    boolean get();

}


package com.mycompany.app.store;

@Component
public class StoreImpl implements Store {
    @Override
    public boolean get()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**=> my main (I test my app with this for now):**

```
public class App
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Controller controller = new Controller();
        controller.use();
    }
}
```

=> my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>my-app</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.0.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

  <dependencies>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.jsoup</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsoup</artifactId>
          <version>1.7.1</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
          <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
          <version>1.12.6</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>




      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
          <version>${spring.version}</version>
      </dependency>


      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
          <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
      </dependency>


      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
          <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
          <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
      </dependency>

      <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.1</version>
          <scope>provided</scope>
      </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**=> my web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
         http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/META-INF/spring-context.xml</param-value>

    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

**=> my spring-context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <!--<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.app"/>-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.app">
       <!-- <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" />-->
    </context:component-scan>

</beans>
```

**=> my project architecture**

---

```
my-app
  src
    main
      java
        com.mycompagny.app
          controller
            Controller.java
          store
            Store.java
            StoreImpl.java

          app.java

       ressources
         META-INF
           spring-context.xml

       webapp
         WEB-INF
           web.xml


  test
   java

pom.xml
```

---

=> stacktrace of main()

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.mycompany.app.controller.Controller.run(Controller.java:25)
    at com.mycompany.app.App.main(App.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

So my problem is my injected field (storeImpl) is null.
And I think I miss something with context init ?
Thanks again for your help and yourr grats answer

Comment: What exactly is the problem?

Comment: Define a bean for your Implementation class in the spring xml

Comment: my problem is that my injected field (storeImpl) is null. I think context.xml never initialized. I think with annotation driven I don't need to tag the bean in context.xml ? even I do it, the field is still null :s

Comment: Your question is loooong. Few hints though: only Spring beans can have other Spring beans injected into them. Your controller is not annotated with a Sprig component annotation. Interfaces should not be annotated with component annotations. Their implementation should be. And the type of the injected field (store) should be the type of the interface, not the type of the implementation. So it should be Store, not StoreImpl. I also don't understand why you're repeating the same config in the two xml files (and why you have 2 in the first place).

Comment: You are using component scanning so don't define the beans in the context. Again that leads to bean duplication. At the moment, due to the length and edit of your post I'm quite lost on what you have and why it isn't working. Please rewrite your post with the code you have now, I'm lost.

Comment: ok i'm rewriting the whole post thanks again !

Comment: You aren't using Spring. Your main class isn't doing anything, your configuration is basically useless. You aren't doing anything web related so not sure why you even have a `web.xml`. In your `main` class you are constructing an instance of `Controller` yourself, spring is never going to inject that for you, for that you have to load the xml file and use the `Controller` instance created by Spring.

Comment: thanks a lot ! it works with: 

ApplicationContext ctx = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("classpath:META-INF/spring-context.xml");
        Controller a = (Controller) ctx.getBean("controller");

but I have to defines the beans in spring context, annotations arn't enought :s thanks again for your time and kindness !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a couple of problems (the following are apparent from your post).

1. Mixing jars of different versions of Spring
2. Wrong location of annotations
3. Duplication in your applicationcontext.
4. Using versioned XSD files.
5. Conflicting versioning in web.xml

**1. Mixing Jars of different versions of Spring**

```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.5.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
```

Your pom is littered with jars from different spring versions (3.0.5, 4.0.1, 4.0.3 and 4.0.3). If you want trouble then that is the way to go. Always stick to a single version of a framework and don't mix jars from different versions. This isn't only for Spring but goes for every (multi jar) framework out-there.

Use the power of maven to help you, specify a property to hold the version of Spring you want to use and use that property.

```
<properties>
    <spring.version>4.0.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

You might need to add a couple more depending on which dependencies Spring Data JPA is pulling in, if that has different versions.

**2. Wrong location of annotations**

```
@Service
public interface Store {
    boolean get();
}
```

Annotations aren't inherited from interfaces so putting the annotation on the interface is pretty much useless. Spring has some hacks in place for specific annotations like `@Transactional` but not for this. Move the annotation to the concrete implementation and don't put it on the interface.

```
@Service
public class Controller {
    @Autowired
    private Store storeImpl;

    public void use() {
       storeImpl.get();
    }
}
```

I don't see anything here no `@Controller` or what so ever also no `@RequestMapping` so I'm not sure how you think that Spring detects and handles this class.

**3. Duplication in your applicationcontext.**

`<context:annotation-config />` remove it from your context as that is already implied by the use of `<context:component-scan />`.

`<mvc:annotation-driven />` should be only in the xml file loaded by the `DispatcherServlet` in your case (if you have posted actual code) that should be the `dispatcher-servlet.xml`.

You have the same `<context:component-scan .. />` element in both your xml files, this will ead to bean duplication. The files loaded by the `ContextLoaderListener` should load anything but `@Controllers` and the `DispatcherServlet` should load only `@Controllers` and ignore anything else. To accomplish that use include/exclude filters when component scanning.

Use this for the `ContextLoaderListener`.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.app">
    <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype. Controller" />
<context:component-scan>
```

Use this for the `DispatcherServlet`.

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.app" use-default-filters="false >
    <context:include-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype. Controller" />
<context:component-scan>
```

Also don't import the configuration of the `DispatcherServlet` into the `ContextLoaderListener` as this will again lead to bean duplication.

**4. Using versioned XSD files.**

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
```

Your schema locations use versioned XSD files, it is recommended to use versionless xsd files. This will ensure that the xsd version belonging to your current spring version will be loaded.

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
```

**5. Conflicting versioning in web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
    "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
```

What is it you want version 2.3 of 2.4? You including servlet-api 2.5 in your pom and I would expect that you want version 3.0. Change your header (and maven dependency) accordingly.

Change your `web.xml` header to the following.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
     version="3.0">
```

Update your pom.xml to include the servlet 3.0 spec.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks for you great answer ! very usefull ! I made some changes but I  still have my issue :s So I'm editing my question to be more specific

Comment: I just finished rewriting the whole post in order to clarify things. thanks again !!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to define the bean in your Spring xml

```
<bean id="storeImpl" class="com.mycompany.app.store.StoreImpl">
       <!-- collaborators and configuration for this bean go here -->
</bean>
```

So, the `@Autowired` bean will be injected by Spring framework