# Integrating Spring 4.0.5 + Hibernate 4.3.5 + C3P0 9.2.1

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, datasource, c3p0

I've seen several similar questions, but none of the suggested solutions helped me.

We are migrating an application to Spring 4.0.5 + Hibernate 4.3.5 + C3P0 9.2.1 and we are experiencing problems with the transactions/sessions.

ApplicationContext:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.servicetonic.sdesk" />
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

    <bean id="contextApplicationContextProvider" class="com.servicetonic.sdesk.util.context.ApplicationContextProvider"></bean>
    <bean id="dataSource" name="sDeskBD"
          class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource" 
          destroy-method="close" > 
        <!-- Driver  -->
        <property name="driverClass"><value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value></property>
        <property name="jdbcUrl"><value>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbst</value></property>
        <property name="user"><value>root</value></property>
        <property name="password"><value>AzulBlanco09</value></property>
        <!-- Tamanyo del pool  -->
        <property name="initialPoolSize"><value>1</value></property>
        <property name="minPoolSize"><value>1</value></property>
        <property name="acquireIncrement"><value>1</value></property>
        <property name="maxPoolSize"><value>50</value></property> 
        <!-- Vigencia de las conexiones--> 
        <property name="maxIdleTime"><value>7200</value></property>    
        <!-- Test de las conexiones  -->
        <property name="automaticTestTable"><value>STTestTable</value></property>
        <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod"><value>300</value></property>
        <property name="testConnectionOnCheckin"><value>true</value></property>
        <!-- Ejecucion de sentencias -->
        <property name="maxStatements"><value>0</value></property>   
        <property name="maxStatementsPerConnection"><value>0</value></property> 
        <!-- Recuperacion de caidas de BBDD-->
        <property name="acquireRetryAttempts"><value>60</value></property>
        <property name="acquireRetryDelay"><value>1000</value></property>
        <property name="breakAfterAcquireFailure"><value>false</value></property> 
        <!-- Soporte a TX pendientes -->
        <property name="autoCommitOnClose"><value>false</value></property> 
        <!-- Otras configuraciones  -->
        <property name="numHelperThreads"><value>5</value></property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="/WEB-INF/config/hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.servicetonic.sdesk" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Hibernate config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC  
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.query.substitutions">true 'Y', false 'N'</property>
        <!-- Dialecto -->
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.use_outer_join">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.session_factory_name">hibernate</property>
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.factory_class">org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">30</property>

        <!-- Configuracion pool c3p0 -->
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">50</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">5</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">300</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
        <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">7200</property>

        <!-- Mapping -->
        <mapping class="com.servicetonic.sdesk.modelo......"/>
        .....

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

DAO Implementation:

```
@Repository
public class SpringHibernateDAO implements DAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public <T> List<T> find(String hql) {
        final List<T> entities = getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql).list();
        return entities;
    }

    @Override
    public Session getCurrentSession() {
        return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }

    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public void setSessionFactory(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
    }

    .....
}
```

with this configuration i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-9" org.hibernate.HibernateException: createQuery is not valid without active transaction
    at org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:352)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy128.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    at com.servicetonic.sdesk.services.dao.impl.SpringHibernateDAO.find(SpringHibernateDAO.java:54)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:262)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:95)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:207)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.find(Unknown Source)
    at com.servicetonic.sdesk.services.tools.impl.PatchServiceImpl.getPatchs(PatchServiceImpl.java:50)
    at com.servicetonic.sdesk.services.global.ProcessServicePackRunnable.run(ProcessServicePackRunnable.java:72)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

If we remove the property hibernate.current_session_context_class = thread Then we get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: No Session found for current thread
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext.currentSession(SpringSessionContext.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.getCurrentSession(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1014)
    at com.servicetonic.sdesk.services.dao.impl.SpringHibernateDAO.getCurrentSession(SpringHibernateDAO.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy79.obtenerSesion(Unknown Source)
    at com.servicetonic.sdesk.services.jdbc.impl.JdbcServiceImpl.executeQuery(JdbcServiceImpl.java:184)
    at com.servicetonic.sdesk.services.global.impl.TranslateServiceImpl.getTraduccionesLV(TranslateServiceImpl.java:104)
    at com.servicetonic.sdesk.services.global.impl.TranslateServiceImpl.createTranslateMap(TranslateServiceImpl.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy95.createTranslateMap(Unknown Source)
    at com.servicetonic.sdesk.views.beans.application.ApplicationManagedBean.init(ApplicationManagedBean.java:41)
    at com.servicetonic.sdesk.views.beans.application.ApplicationManagedBean.<init>(ApplicationManagedBean.java:34)
    at com.servicetonic.sdesk.util.sesion.ContextListener.contextInitialized(ContextListener.java:27)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4765)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5260)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Is your service method `createTranslateMap` annotated with `@Transactional`?

Comment: Don't mess around with `hibernate.current_session_context_class` in a spring application (unless you are using JTA). The exception basically indicates your setup is wrong. In your config your `hibernate.c3p0` settings are useless, as you are using a SPring managed datasource hibernate isn't going to create its own. Your stacktrace cleare indicates that there is nothing transasction related in your setup. Which leads me to the fact that you are creating your beans twice, rendering your `@Transactional` useless, or you have your `<tx:annotation-driven />` in a different context then your beans.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. M.Deinum, I removed the c3p0 properties from hi bernate and the property hibernate.current_session_context_class. Now, how coulsd i know if i have my <tx:annotation-driven /> in a different context then my beans and why?

Comment: If you have a `ContextLoaderListener` and `DispatcherServlet` and both have a `<component-scan />` you are probably scanning for the same classes twice. If you have `<tx:annotation-driven />` in the `ContextLoaderListener` and a `<component-scan >` in the `DispatcherServlet` it isn't going to work as AOP only works on beans in the same context. (And yes AOP is used to apply transactions). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538914/spring-context-init-java/23539343#23539343

Comment: Thank you M. I revised the post and my code, and i didn't find anything wrong. Finally the problem was i didn't annotate one of the method with @Transactional, as James said. James, If you'd like to rephrase your comment as an answer I'd be happy to accept it. Thanks to all of you!